# Fetch data from JSON file in assets folder instead of url

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The following code made to fetch data from url, where I wanted to change it to fetch data from assets folder.

I am new to Flutter, I need your help please. how can I put json file locally instead of url.

I could not factor what changes should be made to the following code so that it can work.

I tried to fix it but I could not, appreciate if someone could help on this.

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'user.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

List data;
List<User> userlist = List();
List<User> usersavedlist = List();
int index;

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'UserList Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('UserList Flutter'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved),
          ],
        ),
        body: listView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    final url =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highmobdevelopment/userlist/master/contacts.json';
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('succesfull parse');

      this.setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        data.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
      });
    }

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: userlist == null ? 0 : userlist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[_buildRow(index, userlist), const Divider()],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(index, userlist) {
    final bool alreadySaved = usersavedlist.contains(userlist[index]);

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        userlist[index].name
```

Looking for your support please to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to declare your json file in your pubspec.yaml file.

```
assets:
    - assets/contacts.json
```

I'm not sure, but then your `fetchData()` method must change to something like this

```
    Future<String> fetchData() async {
        String data = await 
        DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/contacts.json");
        
       final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
       
       this.setState(() {
            jsonResult.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
       });
  
    
      return "Success!";
  }
```

**UPDATE: Try this complete example:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class JsonFromAsset extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _JsonFromAssetState createState() => _JsonFromAssetState();
}

class _JsonFromAssetState extends State<JsonFromAsset> {
  List<User> userlist = [];

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/contacts.json");

    final jsonResult = json.decode(data);

    this.setState(() {
      jsonResult.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchData();
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: userlist.length > 0
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userlist == null ? 0 : userlist.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(child: Text(userlist[index].firstName));
                    },
                  )
                : Center(child: Text('empty'))));
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting empty screen on the emulator, that means nothing fetched

Comment: For me it's working. Did you full restart the app after add the json file to  assets and declare at pubspec.yaml? Hot reload won't update the assets.

Comment: I edited the answer look the complete example. At least for me it's working. Maybe you need to change something else in your class.

Comment: thanks you, I tried the complete example you provided, but also dose not work. i get these errors: 1- The name 'User' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'User'. 2- Undefined class 'User.fromJson'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'User.fromJson'.

Comment: Well, this is weird because in your own code there's an User and a method User.fromJson. Do you have a class named User? Did you tested the code from the question with the URL call? The only thing you should modify is the property userList[index].firstName from my example to userList[index].name, from your own code.

Comment: I created a mock file json named contacts.json, with mock data, and used a mock class named User to reproduce the code. But this should work with your contatcs.json that must reflect a User model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flutters services to load the JSON string. Use the below code.

```
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
    import 'dart:convert' as convert;
    
//For Local JSON File
    loadJsonData()async{
    var rawString= await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
    var jsonData= convert.jsonDecode(rawString);              
    }

//for Remote JSON File

     Future<String> fetchData() async {
     final url ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highmobdevelopment/userlist/master/contacts.json';
        final response = await http.get(url,headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          setState(() {
             data = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
             data.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
          });
        }
    
        return "Success!";
      }
```

Comment: how can I use this code, can please explain further. or amend the whole code that I have provided please

Comment: [see this example from repo](https://github.com/Lokeswara-betha/prime_demo/blob/master/online_shopping_demo/lib/pages/home.dart)

Comment: Sorry, my code is different from the one you gave as an example. if you can amend my code that will be appreciated

Comment: I updated the main comment code. once try with newly added code